# shopify handle app install hook/event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I have shopify rails app using [official gem](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app), I want to handle app install event, is there any hook for this or how i can override controller?

Answer (score 1):

App install is not a Webhook event so much as the process of you recognizing an incoming call to your Apps install route and deciding if it is time to authenticate or not. If it is, you get to decide if it is new install or just an existing merchant.

Once you figure that out (it is pretty much built in to the App already) you an prepare your App to listen to other hooks or events.

Watch the video on using that Shopify Gem, it show you everything you need to do.